# How to fix the error code on this Ppnt word randomiser

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have been trying to create a word randomiser in powerpoint. I have a .txt file in the same location as the powerpoint.  When I click a button on the ppnt slide it should randomly return two words from the .txt file.

Have done some online tutorials and have produced the following.  However, when I run it I always get error code 13 and a type mismatch.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public myArray, Word1, Word2

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)

    If SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide Then
        Randomize
        Label1.Caption = ""
        Label2.Caption = ""
    
        Dim path
        path = ActivePresentation.path & "\words.txt"
        Open path For Input As #1
        filecontent = Input(LOF(1), #1)
        Close #1
    
        myArray = Split(filecontent, vbCrLf)
        
    End If
    
End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Word1 = Int((UBound(myArray, 1)) * Rnd)                   **this line is highlighted when I debug**
Word2 = Int((UBound(myArray, 1)) * Rnd)

    Do While Word2 = Word1
    Word2 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)
    Loop

Label1.Caption = myArray(Word1)
Label2.Caption = myArray(Word2)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing `myArray` hasn't been initialized when the code runs You might want to use a different event than `OnSlideShowPageChange`.

Comment: What are Label1 and Label2? Do you want to actually change the title of the presentation? `Label1.Parent.Application.Caption = ""` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.datalabel.caption , or do you actually want that text to appear in shapes? Or what precisely? Here more reference for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.datalabel

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but needed to post it as such in order to get the code formatted legibly.

If you're working with an ActiveX label on a slide, you need to use something like this to access the Caption property:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    .Shapes("Label1").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "This works"
End With
```

Also, you'll be better off long-term if you develop the habit of dimming your variables explicitly:

Instead of:

```
Public myArray, Word1, Word2
```

Use

```
Public myArray as Variant
Public Word1 as String
Public Word2 as String
```

Likewise, Dim Path as String, but I'd use sPath or something else as the variable name. Using reserved words or existing property names as variables will eventually bite you.

Then:
If SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide

StartingSlide returns a Long, not a Boolean.

If SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide = 1 (or whatever slide you want) would be more reliable.

```
Word1 = Int((UBound(myArray, 1)) * Rnd)
```